# How to create a test account for Facebook account kit?

Tags: objective-c, app-store-connect, itunes, facebook-account-kit

We are developing an iOS App that uses Facebook account kit for login through sms. We uploaded our app on iTunes connect for app review and they are asking for testing credentials for testing the app. But Facebook doesn't provide any test user credentials. Now we want to know how apple can test the app for review. If there is any method to create a test user for Facebook account kit, let me know as soon as possible.
Thanks,

Comment: Hi did you got solution for this ?? @subham

Comment: My app is also stuck in review due to this. Were you able to resolve this, please share.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create an account facebook just go here

To create a Facebook account:
1.Go to www.facebook.com/r.php.
2.Enter your name, email or mobile phone number, password, date of birth and gender.
Click Sign Up.
3.To finish creating your account, you need to confirm your email or mobile phone number.
for more 
http://toptrendinngtoday.com/index.php/2019/09/20/step-by-step-to-make-facebook-and-instagram-account/